# Extract Data Between string with Double Double quotes in Shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I need to extract the data from a large file having double double quotes into a text file. 
The number of columns are fixed but the column will be missing if the data isnt available in a row like acct_address & phne_nm missing in 1st row, phne_num missing in 2nd row, acct_address missing in 3rd row

Data in File

```
<acc_details acct_no=""00000"" acct_nm=""John""/>
<acc_details acct_no=""00001"" acct_address=""109 BIRHN WAY "" acct_nm=""BARNS WY""/>
<acc_details acct_no=""00002"" acct_nm=""BILL BAR"" phne_nm=""123456""/>
```

Expected Result

```
acct_no,acct_address,acct_nm,phne_nm
00000,,John,
00001,109 BIRHN WAY,BARNS WY,
00002,,BILL BAR,123456
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using grep but I am not sure on how to extract handle the missing columns from each line

Comment: Can you post the code you have come up with so far?

Comment: grep -o '".*"' file_name | sed 's/"//g' - I know this is not correct

Comment: In your example `acct_nm=""BILL BAR"` has only a one ending double quote. Is it a typo?

Comment: I have corrected it now as per the requirement. Its a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it should be applicable for most cases. It can be improved upon.

```
echo "acct_no,acct_address,acct_nm,phne_nm" > res
while read line ; do
    acct_no=$(echo $line | grep -Eoh 'acct_no="".*?""' | cut -d\" -f3)
    acct_nm=$(echo $line | grep -Eoh 'acct_nm="".*?""' | cut -d\" -f3)
    acct_address=$(echo $line | grep -Eoh 'acct_address="".*?""' | cut -d\" -f3)
    phne_nm=$(echo $line | grep -Eoh 'phne_nm="".*?""' | cut -d\" -f3)
    echo $acct_no,$acct_address,$acct_nm,$phne_nm >> res
done < file
```

grep and cut can be used to isolate parts of the lines with the matching attribute patterns. Just be warned that any double quote inside the attribute values might cause this code to fail.

Comment: When I run this code, it has 2 issues 1--> Whenever there are 2 spaces between the words in the file, it is coming as just 1 space. For example Source=""My  City is BIRM"" and in extracted file, value=My City is BIRM. 2--> Its taking very long time to process. For 50k records, it took around 20min. I have a million records input file.

Comment: There 2 spaces between My and City in the input value. When its extracted, I need to see 2 spaces only or how it is present in the data

Comment: I don't think spaces are trimmed by this code. Please verify again. And, yes this will be too slow for a large amount of records.

Comment: But if you are have a constraint of using bash, I suppose you could use some variation of the above code to make it more efficient.

Comment: But if you are have a constraint of using bash, I suppose you could use some variation of the above code to make it more efficient. If there is no such constraint, you could rather use some xml parser, which is best suited for cases like this.

Comment: I checked again and the spaces are trimmed. We dont have any XSD sheets for me to use the xml parser. Please help

Comment: Can you post the inputs for which the spaces are trimmed?

Comment: Are acct_no,acct_address,acct_nm,phne_nm attributes in the same order for all entries?

Comment: You can perhaps use some regex like `<acc_details (acct_no=""(.*?)"")?\s?(acct_address=""(.*?)"")?\s?(acct_nm=""(.*?)"")?\s?(phone_nm=""(.*?)"")?\s?\/>` and match the xml line.

Comment: Now, I am getting the data in the below format. Please help                                                   <acc_details acct_no="00000" acct_nm="John"/>
<acc_details acct_no=""00001"" acct_address="109 BIRHN WAY " acct_nm="BARNS WY"/>
<acc_details acct_no="00002" acct_nm="BILL BAR" phne_nm="123456"/>. There are no double quotes

Comment: No double quotes? or no double double quotes. The line seems to have both.

Comment: No double double quotes. Also, need an example for regex

Comment: I am not sure if regex would be a very big improvement. The above approach should actually be better. And I'm sure spaces won't get trimmed. Can you post the example i/p and o/p where the spaces are trimmed?

Comment: I changed the code with acct_no=$(echo "$line" | grep -Eoh 'acct_no=".*?"' | cut -d '"' -f2). Now I am able to extract data in double quotes and also the spaces are not getting truncated. i changed the code from $line to "$line" as the echo will remove spaces. Thanks

Comment: Yes. There was no reason for truncation. If this answer helped you on your issue, please mark it as accepted.